# jquery - if form validate returns false - then remove display:none from html span tag

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form. and jquery to validate that a field was filled out properly. If it returns false then I want to remove a span styles display:none, making the error message visible.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()" action="something.php">
<div id="name-field" class="form_stuff">
<span class="error-bubble" style="display:none">
<span class="error-message">This is invalid</span>
</span>
<label id="name-label" for="name_name">Name</label>
<input id="name_name" type="text" tabindex="2" name="name">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function Validate(){
var minLength = 5;
var blockedNames = ["Hello12","World12"];
var fName = $('#name_name').val();
if(fName.length < minLength){
    $('#error').show();
    $('#name_name').focus();
    return false;
}
for(var i = 0;i < blockedNames.length;i++){
    if(fName == blockedNames[i]){
        $('#error').show();
        $('#name_name').focus();
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

How can I add into this script that if it returns false then to remove DISPLAY:NONE from inside the style atribute in the span tag? So if they don't enter their name correctly the HTML will change to

```
<span class="error-bubble" style="">
```

Of course then making the error message visible... Thanks for your help in avance!

Comment: Doesn't `$(".error-bubble").show()` do what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I'm a total JS newbie. How would I implement that into the script to check if it works? Thats my problem is I'm not understanding the syntax to know where to place it.

Comment: Put it right before `return false`.

Comment: Whoa weird, that works. And it does exactly the effect I was wanting to achieve, it erases the display:none field in the HTML. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can show it using

```
$(".error-bubble").show();
```

and you can hide it using

```
$(".error-bubble").hide();
```

Comment: Ok thank you I'm sure that is a lot easier. But WHERE in the script would that go? everything I try doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, the user above answered, place it before return false. It works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @randyttp, if the answer helped you, then you might consider accepting it, so future visitors will know where to look for the solution.